# How to reset Sales Order after day end

Tags: magento-1.9

How to reset the sales order after day end as per below example 01/11/2015
sales order number is 0001,0002,0003 to 1000 02/11/2015 sales order number                        is 0001,0002,0003 to 1100 03/11/2015 sales order number is 0001,0002,0003 to 1500.

Comment: Why you want that? Order number should be unique.

Comment: I want to display customer orders as increment way regards date